# Spring security OAUTH 2.0 add new Client to the application

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I am trying to implement Spring OAuth 2.0 SSO, but i am unable to find a way to 
ADD NEW CLIENT to the running app once it has started.

Adding new users is possible but i have been unable to find any way to add new CLIENTS to the app. please let me know if there is any way to do so.

I can only add Clients to the app a while it is booting up.

Comment: what url are u following??

Comment: i am making my own app and following the code example from http://spring.io/blog/2015/02/03/sso-with-oauth2-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-v

Comment: what "client" do you mean? client-app? ("client" is oAuth terminology)

Comment: You need to be more specific at your question. It is very hard to understand what you are looking for at you question

Comment: Well sir in spring oauth... we can add a client as follows                    \n

Comment: Yes i want to do and addition to the OAuth2.0 client and in  example (http://spring.io/blog/2015/02/03/sso-with-oauth2-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-v)   @Override public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients)  {  clients.jdbc(dataSource).withClient("polymer".secret("poly").authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code","refresh_token","password").scopes("openid") .autoApprove(false); }  which is done this way as in the example. But this works (i.e. adds client to the list) only when the app is booting up. I want to know how to do it afterwards too once the app has started.